# PHP - Cannot get variables posted with PUT

Tags: php, put

I do a `PUT` request but I cannot access the posted data, I always get `string(0) ""` back.

The code I'm using for getting the `PUT` data is:

```
public function editProduct($id) {

    $put = file_get_contents('php://input',true);

    return var_dump($put);
}
```

The `PUT` request is

```
thanasisem@debian:~$ curl -i -X PUT -d arg=123 -d arg2=345 localhost/laravelproject/public/products/5
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 30 Jun 2014 17:22:59 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u11
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjdcL3dYVlM1ZXZOZ0JHMVQrb1o1ME1sa3c3QTdTNnRXUnhxTWFDeHJSVDBJPSIsInZhbHVlIjoicTVPb2QwdThNRE1xUnh4VWZnWW5FT3ZTQUxKaE1RdWtycjNVUmlPWVZCZmVNcVBaVFY0Z0k1bEpSV0phVG5TckNWSkh1S2tsR1NEbmxvcFpna3lDOEE9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImI4ZmRlZTM1ODAyNDY3YjY5ZGQyZTE5NGZiMTEzZWVlOWUzZDIyZTI4MmE3MjM4MDM5NGFkZTRjOWQ4Yzk2OGQifQ%3D%3D; expires=Mon, 30-Jun-2014 19:22:59 GMT; path=/; httponly
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

string(0) ""
thanasisem@debian:~$
```

Comment: I assume this is in the context of a function?  Show all of your code required to reproduce this.

Comment: Just updated the code.

Comment: No errors?  If you echo something after your call to `editProduct()`, do you see its output?

Comment: Seems like file_get_contents does not work. Function is executed. $put is something like null.

Comment: If it were `null`, you would see that in your output.  I don't believe you when you say that you see nothing, but that there are no errors.

Comment: Its empty not null. Sorry.

Comment: You're saying that your output says:  `string(0) ""`?

Comment: Exactly. This is the output I get.

Comment: If that's the case, then `file_get_contents()` is working fine.  Show a packet capture of your request, and edit  your question to include what you're getting back.

Comment: Let me update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I had to put `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'` in my `PUT` request in order for it to work.

A successful `PUT` request that I created is the following:

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"firstName":"Kris", "lastName":"Jordan"}' localhost/laravelproject/public/products/5
```

Answer (score 0):

RTM: http://php.net/var_dump

`var_dump` does immediate output, and has a `void` return type. So you're outputting whatever you uploaded, and then returning essentially nothing.

You probably want

```
return file_get_contents('php://input');
```

instead.

Comment: It shouldn't matter Marc, he should see the output of `var_dump`.  He's added more information in the comments above.  There's something wrong with the request.